# Cross domain ajax POST ie7 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7, xdomainrequest

been having trouble with this script, ive managed to get it working in ie8, works on chrome fine.

```
initilize: function(){
 $('#my_form').submit(function(){
  if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {     
   var data = $('#my_form').serialize();
   xdr=new XDomainRequest();
   function after_xhr_load()
   {
    response = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
    if(response.number =="incorrect format"){
     $('#errors').html('error');
    }
    else
    {
     $('#errors').html('worked');
    }
   }
   xdr.onload = after_xhr_load;
   xdr.open("POST",$('#my_form').attr('action')+".json");
   xdr.send(data);

  } else {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('#my_form').attr('action')+".json",
    data: $('#my_form').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function(data) {
     if(data.statusText =="OK"){
      $('#errors').html('error');
     }
     if(data.statusText =="Created"){
      response = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
      $('#errors').html('Here is your code:' +response.code);
     }
    }
  });
 }
 return false;
});
}
```

I understand that ie7 does not have the XDomainRequest() object. How can I replicate this in ie7.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Maybe your looking for JSONP, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: Simple answer is you can't replicate it in IE7 without changing to a same-domain request or using JSONP rather than CORS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not going to get that code to work in IE7 since is cross domain calls are not supported in that old browser. You either need to change the backend to do a JSONP call or you need to use a serverside proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i figured as much.